# How to handle SQL Server XML stored procedure parameters when table valued parameters (TVP's) are unavailable?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, xml-parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

When you don't have SQL Server 2008 to play with (TVP's), the advantage of passing in a XML parameter into a SPROC is that if your parameter requirements change, you don't have to recompile/etc. your app to comply.

I'm of the notion that keeping the data as XML in a table field isn't the best idea, that the sproc should then parse the incoming XML and populate the relevant fields in the table.  However, we can also easily do SELECT / filter queries on XML contained within a field in a table.

What kind of latency is introduced in parsing out the XML and populating the appropriate fields, and is anything gained by doing this?

In a high-traffic environment, which is the best policy?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. This is a very broad question. Usually a lot of processing is required for parsing the XML (without XML indexes in this case). Is your high-traffic inserting heavily or selecting heavily?

There is potentially a lot of gains in parsing in to a table, if they are applicable. If you do not need to query it and you are storing XML to later return it in the same form then there is less to gain.

It definitely depends on the rest of the data in the table and how much time you have for inserting/updating vs selecting and other maintenance. A good medium may be to insert the XML with an index. 
There is no best policy that I am aware of but I would aim to parse it at insert time and store it in separate fields with the benefits of referential integrity, indexes, faster queries and reduced storage costs, to name a few.

You can use query plans and wait stats when comparing different approaches.

Comment: This is will be a very high-traffic operation, and as such I'm thinking that I may opt for no XML parsing.  The input parameters probably won't change, and if they do it really won't be an issue for me to simply modify the sproc signature.  In the past, I have saved the raw XML and only parsed out the fields required, opting not to fully parse out the XML as requirements didn't dictate so.  I was looking for some performance metrics in parsing out XML with SQL Server.